Underconstrained linear system, finding solution closest to $w_0\ne 0$?
How do I find solution of an under-constrained linear system in $\mathbb{R}^d$ that is closest to given reference $w_0$ in Euclidean distance?
Below is a solution that uses QuadraticOptimization, however that requires writing out the formulas symbolically. For $d=1000$, there are 1 million symbolic variables, is there a more efficient approach?
norm2[mat_] := Total@Flatten[mat*mat];
modifiedLeastSquares[m_, b_, w0_] := Module[{xx, x, eqs, d},
   d = Last@Dimensions[b];
   x = Array[xx, {d, d}];
   eqs = Flatten@MapThread[#1 == #2 &, {m . x, b}, 2];
   x /. QuadraticOptimization[norm2[x - w0], eqs, Flatten@x]
   ];

SeedRandom[1];
bs = 4;
d = 8;
m = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {bs, d}];
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {bs, d}];
w0 = ConstantArray[0, {d, d}];
mySol = modifiedLeastSquares[m, b, w0];
refSol = LeastSquares[m, b];
Print["Difference from built-in LeastSquares: ", 
 mySol - refSol // Norm]


Interesting question. To clarify: (1) Is $w_{0}$ a point in $R^d$ or a point in $R^{d\times d}$? (The former case might be easier.) (2) LeastSquares[ ] tries to minimize $||mx-b||^{2}$, not $||x||^2$. Why do you use it as a reference?

@A.Kato I believe you are considering overconstrained case. In underconstrained case, LeastSquares minimizes ||x||^2 subject to $mx-b=0$, the code above numerically checks that this formulation matches output of LeastSquares

Thank you for your answer.

The explanation given in Details and Options of the documentation LeastSquares is misleading .....

Rather irrelevant to the main problem, but, FYI, Norm[mat, "Frobenius"] is built-in, but it's a tad slower (probably because it squares the absolute value of the entries). And norm2[mat_] := Total[mat*mat, 2] is a tad faster than your norm2[].

@A.Kato If the solution of LeastSquare[m,b] isn't unique, Mathematica returns the minimal solution Min[Norm[x]]I think

@UlrichNeumann I agree with you, and that is the same as the OP's reply to my question. But this behavior is not documented yet, I think...

@A.Kato that's a consequence of pseudo-inverse, if you have $Y=WX$ and you define $W=YX^\dagger$, it either gives minimum error or minimum norm solution depending on whether system is under/overconstrained

@YaroslavBulatov Pseudo-inverse! That makes total sense.

Your problem

Find $x$ such that $m.x=b$ and $||x-w_{0}||^2\to $ min

is equivalent to (by change of variables $y=x+w_{0}$)

Find $y$ such that $m.y=b-m.w_{0}$ and $||y||^2\to $ min

So, the simplest answer is:
LeastSquares[m, b - m . w0] + w0

This solves the case of $d=1000$ and $bs=500$ within 1.2 seconds on my PC.

aha, thanks, it was a simple re-arrangement after all

You are welcome :-)  I also learned a lot.
